# Does the cinematic version of Titanic (1997) include Rose Dawson's and J. Bruce Ismay's first steps on the Carpathia?

Tags: titanic

I do not remember seeing what starts from 59:56 towards the end of this [extract](https://youtu.be/cMVi953awHQ?t=59m56s) (which exhibits Rose Dawson's and J. Bruce Ismay's first steps on the ship *Carpathia*)  in the original 3h 17m version of the 1997 movie *Titanic* (which exhibits only the lifeboats' approach towards the Carpathia, followed by Cal's searching for Rose on her deck and Rose's evading him by wearing a head covering).

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer with Google: the aforesaid (entitled 'the extended *Carpathia* sequence') are deleted scenes:

http://rebloggy.com/post/gifs-titanic-kate-winslet-rose-dewitt-bukater-antostuff-deleted-scene-extended/59211208455

[image]

(now deleted)

[image]